Expo/React Native RTL layout resets after app restart on production APK despite initial RTL setup
I'm building a RTL app that needs to be RTL regardless of device settings. My RTL setup works on the first app launch, but after closing and reopening the app, the layout reverts to LTR. Current code:
// index.tsx
    import {useFonts} from "expo-font";
import AppNavigator from "@/app/AppNavigator";
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import {AuthProvider} from "@/contexts/AuthContext";
import moment from 'moment-jalaali';
import {I18nManager} from 'react-native';


I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
I18nManager.allowRTL(true);
I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
I18nManager.swapLeftAndRightInRTL(false);

export default function Page() {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    ...
  });
  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

  moment.loadPersian({
    usePersianDigits: true,
    dialect: 'persian-modern'
  });

  return (
       <AuthProvider>
         <AppNavigator />
       </AuthProvider>
  );
}

Environment:
Expo SDK 50
React Native 0.73.2
Production APK build

Can anyone help with maintaining RTL layout consistently across app restarts?
